Help reversing Xilinx firmware
I have a binary file which can be flashed onto a FPGA board
That being said, I am trying to reverse this firmware to understand it and just as learning experience
After running binwalk;
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
44            0x2C            Xilinx Virtex/Spartan FPGA bitstream dummy + sync word
533271        0x82317         Intel x86 or x64 microcode, sig 0x00011020, pf_mask 0x2000420, 2001-11-03, rev 0x0012, size 744
1195942       0x123FA6        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x60, dictionary size: 115267128 bytes, uncompressed size: 64 bytes
1420056       0x15AB18        Intel x86 or x64 microcode, sig 0x00104400, pf_mask 0x40016010, 2022-18-01, rev 0x-feafe14, size 66666
1564327       0x17DEA7        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x48, dictionary size: 1157672 bytes, uncompressed size: 88 bytes

After running binwalk -E; I see that the entropy averages around 0.5 (min 0.2, max 0.7) and it fluctuates up and down.
After running binwalk -Me; I get 4 files extracted
- 96AF72
- 96AF72.7z
- 56CD18
- 56CD18.7z

Every tutorial I've seen, there is an extracted subdirectory where they can ls and see information, however this is not my case
I've tried opening the 7z files with an archiver to no avail
What should I deduce from the information I'm presented with and what would be the next steps at reversing this firmware
I'm new to reverse engineering so any help would mean a lot
